# How to resolve NoSuchFileException for Files.createDirectories

Tags: java, linux, nio, create-directory

On a production Linux env, Im getting **NoSuchFileException** for **Files.createDirectories** api.
I have checked the java docs for **Files.createDirectories** and it inherently does not throw this exception.
I need to know on what condition do we get this error for the **Files.createDirectories** API.

```
stackTrace
-----------
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /folder1/folder2/folder abc/ABC-UVW XYZ
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
```

### Code

```
if(!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
    Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(file.getParent()));
    //Files.createDirectories() should create all non existent parent directories but instead it throws NoSuchFileException.
    //......other code
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are spaces allowed?

Comment: @MensurQulami Yes

Comment: Could it be that any of the folders that you want to create already exists as a normal file, not directory? I've found this bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7030716

Comment: from the code review I dont think that's the case. 
Since this is a production env, there's no way I can verify this.

Comment: Were you java application running in a Docker container?

Comment: Yes the java application is run inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

This code throws `FileAlreadyExistsException` for `Files.createDirectories`:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.createDirectories(Path.of("A/B"));
    Files.createFile(Path.of("A/B/C"));

    // throws FileAlreadyExistsException("A/B/C")
    Files.createDirectories(Path.of("A/B/C"));
  }
```

Which is expected behaviour according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)); it failed to create a directory because a file (`C`) with the same name already exists.

You can handle it by deleting the file provided by [`FileSystemException.getFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystemException.html#getFile()) and trying `Files.createDirectories` again.

---

However - this code throws `NoSuchFileException`:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.createDirectories(Path.of("A/B"));
    Files.createFile(Path.of("A/B/C"));

    // throws NoSuchFileException("A/B/C/D")
    Files.createDirectories(Path.of("A/B/C/D/E"));
  }
```

Because the parent of `D` is a file.

You can handle it similarly by deleting the parent of the file provided by `getFile()` and trying `Files.createDirectories` again.

It's strange because it's not explained in the javadoc. I would expect the same `FileAlreadyExistsException` as in the first example.

---

Also there's an inconsistency between the exceptions; `FileAlreadyExistsException.getFile()` uses relative path while `NoSuchFileException.getFile()` uses absolute path. So take that into account when handling the exceptions.